# Insert the ID of the selected value in database from dropdown list in ASP.NET core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dropdown, razor-pages

I am trying to select a value from the dropdown list and pass the selected value to the database . How do I do it?

Following is my code in cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Class_Info.Instructor" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Class_Info.Instructor" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Instructors">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            </select>
```

I am populating the dropdown list for instructors in OnGetAsync method and want to save the ID of it in in OnPostAsync. This is the code in cshtml.cs file :

```
[BindProperty]
    public ClassModel Class_Info { get; set; }

    public IList<Student> UserProfile { get; set; }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public SelectList Instructors { get; set; }
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var students = from s in _context.User_Profile
                     select s;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            students = students.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(SearchString));
        }

        UserProfile = await students.ToListAsync();
        var instructors = from i in _context.Instructor
                          orderby i.FirstName
                          select i;

       
        Instructors = new SelectList(instructors, "InstructorID", "FirstName");
       
    }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Class.Add(Class_Info);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Please advise...

Comment: You should update your question to include what problem you have encountered.

Comment: Hi @JeremyLakeman, I am new to ASP.NET Core and I do not know how to pass the value  of the selected option. Trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You have binded `Class_Info.Instructor` with the selected value of DropDown.So if you want to get the selected value in OnPostAsync,you only need to use `Class_Info.Instructor`.

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou, Class and INstructor table are connected. Class table has InstructorID in it. I want to make sure when I click on Create button, The ID of the selected option should be added to the InstructorID column in the database. This is what I am unsure about. Is EntityFramework taking care of it automatically or Do I need write the code for InstructorID specifically?

Comment: You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic) about basic save.